# Encryption independent of ubuntu os?

Tags: server, hard-drive, encryption, luks, disk-management

I want to set up a ubuntu server (20.04.1) and encrypt some hard drives for the server. Those hdd are not the drives of os installation.

Let's assume that for any reason the installation boot hdd would crash and I would need to replace it.

Can a completly fresh installation of ubuntu read the encrypted hdd (with pw provided of course)?

Is this dependent of the encryption-type (I heared there where several options like eCryptfs, fscrypt or LUKS)?

Is this depentent of the os-version (later releases of ubuntu server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Encryption is done as an extra layer between the disk and the OS.

One thing you do need to take into account: you really should use the same software version en encryption tools the encryption is done with. If your Ubuntu 20.04 crashes and you install Ubuntu 18.04 (so a lower version) the encryption software might have used new features not available in 18.04.

> Let's assume that for any reason the installation boot hdd would crash and I would need to replace it.

Encryption is not a replacement for backups even if you have problems restoring a system from an encrypted disk you will always have backups.

Set your system up such that you 100% split it into a system disk and user disk where the user disk holds every change you make to the system disk. Create a script that copies those backups files to the original location.

Result of this: New system disk -> Install Ubuntu -> Run script -> Done.

Not just handy to replace crashed system disks but also makes transitioning to a new Ubuntu version (ie 18 -> 20 -> 22) a breeze with almost zero risks.

Comment: thank you! I wouldn't downgrade anyway but if I need to re-install, I maybe want to upgrade to a new version. Furthermore, what do you exactly mean by "_100% split it into a system disk and user disk where the user disk holds every change you make to the system disk. Create a script that copies those backups files to the original location._" ? I thought of installing ubuntu on hdd1 and have hdd2 for the media files. Do you mean that I also have a seperate location for the user folder? Or a folder for settings? How would I achive that, which ressources would you recommend (documentation e.g.)?